# Cannot call method unless its global from a class

Tags: python, disco

Hi I am new to Disco and integrating existing code to it. Is Disco capable to call map/reduce function as a function within a class instead of global function? The following code might explain more clearly.

```
class Segmenter(object):
    def map_fun(line, params):
        ....
    def reduce_fun(iter, params):
        ....
    def disco_mp(self):
        job = Job().run(input=["raw://word_to_segment_......"],
                        map=map_fun,
                        reduce=reduce_fun)
        ...
```

The result of execution is

```
NameError: global name 'map_fun' is not defined
```

But if I change map_fun, reduce_fun into global function, it would work fine as expected.
However I still have to find a way to make it work as class functions, is there any way to 
do it ?

Thanks,

Chandler

Comment: What does the title of your question have to do with what you are actually asking?

Comment: The methods of a class should have `self` as the first parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need static method, you can do this with decorator:

```
class Segmenter(Job):
    map = staticmethod(map_fun)
    reduce = staticmethod(reduce_fun)

    @staticmethod
    def map_fun(line, params):
        ....

    @staticmethod
    def reduce_fun(iter, params):
        ....

    def disco_mp(self):
        job = self.run(input=["raw://word_to_segment_......"])
```

Note that you will not have access to `self` in both map_fun and reduce_fun, and this is why `params` exists. Also note that `Job.run` is now `self.run` and `Segmenter` extends `Job`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to use `self.map_fun` and `self.reduce_fun`.  Methods of objects can't be accessed by their bare names in Python; you have to use `self`.  You will also need to provide a `self` argument to those methods.  You should read [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) to familiarize yourself with the basics of classes and methods in Python.

(Also, why is the title of your question unrelated to the actual question?)

Comment: You will need to edit your question, showing your new code and the new error.

Comment: Yeah, I changed code to  
`map=self.map_fun,`  
`reduce=self.reduce_fun)`

 
The error become this.


ModUtilImportError: No module named Segmenter: Could not find module defined in map_fun. Maybe it is a typo. See documentation of the required_modules parameter for details on how to include modules.